# Prove Halting on all Inputs is not in RE simulation

Tags: turing-machines, computability, proof-techniques, semi-decidability, simulation

I don't understand why when proving if Halting on all inputs problem si not in RE using the complement of the halting problem, I have to take a turing machine and simulate the machine M(the machine that the halting problem receives as input) on w(the word received as input) for n steps.

Can somebody explain to me who is n and why do we need to simulate M for n steps? Why not only once?

For proving that halting on all inputs problem is not in RE, the complement of halting problem is used. Supposed we take M(w) as the turing machine used for halting problem, I get the next simulation:

M'= simulate M(w) for n steps;
        if M(w) halts, make it loop
        else, stop.

I don't understand why do I have to make M' simulate M(w) for N STEPS. Why can't I just simulate it one and that's it?

N stands for the length of the word. I don't understand the simulation for a number of steps. Why is that?

Comment: Can you add a reference to the textbook you are using in the question? All users are not using the same textbook as you. Or you can copy the full or just the relevant text of that proof in the question.

Comment: @Apass.Jack did my best to prove more information

Comment: Unless you explain the entire proof, it will be very hard to answer this question. We also don't know what $n$ stands for.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I try my best to prove all the information, but that is all it was written..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the Halting on all inputs problem? It is the problem about the language $$TOTAL=\{⟨M⟩\mid M \text{ is a TM and }M\text{ halts on all inputs} \}.$$

What is the complement of the Halting problem? It is the problem about the language $$\overline{HALT}= \{⟨M, w⟩\mid M \text{ is a TM and }M\text{ does not halt on input } w\}.$$

---

Given a word $⟨M, w⟩$ where $M$ is a Turing machine and $w$ is a input word, how can we construct a new Turing machine in a way that is similar to/the same as how a Turing machine is described in $TOTAL$?

> $M'$ = simulate $M(w)$ for $n$ steps; if $M(w)$ halts, make it loop else, stop.

The construction above is not clear as the meaning of $n$ is defined. Let us clarify that $n$ is the length of the input string. Here is a clear construction of $M'$, where $|x|$ is the length of $x$.

> $M' = $ "On input string $x$, simulate $M$ with input $w$ as long as possible but for no more than $|x|$ steps. If the simulation ever halts, continue to loop forever; otherwise, halt."

Now you should be able to check that
$$⟨M, w⟩\in\overline{HALT} \Longleftrightarrow M'\in TOTAL.$$

---

> I don't understand why do I have to make M' simulate M(w) for N STEPS. Why can't I just simulate it one and that's it?

The "N" in "N STEPS" depends on the input to $M'$. It is a variable independent of $M'$.

Comment: Let me see if I understood this correctly. It is like, when simulating M for M', you take just a finite part of the inputs w' and simulate M for them in order to see if M will halt or not and if M halts, then you make it loop so that the statement for TOTOAL(TOTOAL halts on all inputs) would be true?

Comment: No. Given any input $w'$, $M'$ changes it to a number, $n$ using $E$. Then $M'$ simulates $M$ on input $w$ for $n$ steps. Note that $w'$ has **nothing** to do with $w$. (Hmm, I should have used $x$ instead of $w'$ to prevent relating $w$ to $w'$.)

Comment: And why is a number of steps needed? I mean, M(w) won't have the same behaviour everytime especially beacuse it's related to the same input w on and on?

Comment: Please think from the following perspective first. How do you construct a Turing machine $M'$? You need to specify how $M'$ runs given **any** input $x$. Now how can you specify that? how? how? how? We have infinitely many such $x$.

Comment: Running $M'$ a certain number of times to see it's behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by $M'$? We want to specify $M'$. How to specify the behavior of $M'$ when the input is, say $a$? $aa$? $aaa$? $aaaa$? Tell me how $M'$ will behave given one of those inputs. First, just tell me how $M'$ will behave given $a$, please. Then given $aa$, please. Then given $aaa$, please. And so on.

Comment: Sorry, we need to simulate $M$ for a number of steps given by the computed number by $E$? First it will be for $a$, then for $aa$, then for $aaa$ and so on?

Comment: Yes. That is about the only reasonable and easy way to specify the behavior of $M'$.

Comment: And in general, when we need to specify the behaviour of a machine for a problem that would have to deal with "do something for all inputs", we always use the number of steps?

Comment: There are different ways to specify the behavior of machine given different initial conditions. We use the number of steps here because we want to reduce the complement of the Halting problem to the Halting-on-all-input problem.

Comment: I think I understood somehow. Thank you very much!