# Is the set of Turing machines that halt on infinitely many inputs not recursively enumerable?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, halting-problem, recursively-enumerable

Consider this "generalized halting problem":
$$
GHP = \{<M>| \mbox{ there are infinitely many inputs that $M$ halts on}\}.
$$

I'd like to prove that $GHP\notin RE$, but it doesn't seem straightforward easy.

Any ideas?

---

My first thought was to try the opposite: suppose that there were at most $k$ halting inputs. Then we can recognize these inputs (e.g., run all inputs of length $\le i$ for $i$ steps, for $i=0,1,\ldots$, until you find $k$ halting inputs.)

This almost shows that $GPH\in \overline{RE}$, only that we don't know $k$, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Here is  a [proof](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/103648/prove-halting-on-all-inputs-is-not-in-re-simulation) of a similar statement. Maybe it helps you to think of a analogous proof for your problem.

Comment: @plshelp - Thanks. I've seen it; can you explain why it's analogous?

Comment: I think there's some difficulty in that we don't know which inputs, and there are infinitely many.

Comment: You are right, I think [Rice's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem) is what you are looking for. In fact it directly implies that your language is undecidable.

Comment: @plshelp Note that the question isn't asking whether the language GHP is decidable, but rather whether it's r.e. - lots of r.e. languages are undecidable (e.g. the halting problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, GHP is very far from r.e. - it is [$\Pi^0_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy)-complete, meaning that in particular it is strictly more complicated (in the sense of [Turing reducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction)) than any r.e. set. This includes the halting problem itself; in fact, GHP is Turing-equivalent to "[the halting problem's halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump)." Soare's book *Recursively enumerable sets and degrees* contains a proof of this and similar results; there, GHP is called "$\mathsf{Inf}$" instead.

If you just want to show that GHP is not r.e., a "baby" version of the full argument suffices: it's enough to show that the complement of the halting problem is [many-one reducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction) to GHP; this is because no properly $\Pi^0_1$ set (such as the complement of the halting problem) can ever be many-one reducible to a $\Sigma^0_1$ (= r.e.) set. To do this we argue as follows: given a machine $M$, let $N_M$ be the machine which on input $n$ first tests whether $M(0)$ halts within $n$ steps, and halts and outputs $7$ (say) if it doesn't and goes into an endless loop if it does. Crucially, "halts within $n$ steps" **is** something we can computably check, so the construction $M\leadsto N_M$ actually makes sense. Clearly $N_M$ halts on infinitely many inputs iff $M(0)$ never halts, so we've reduced the complement of (one version of) the halting problem to GHP.

A more detailed version of this idea gives the general reduction of any $\Pi^0_2$ set to GHP.